# Disable Next Button Until Checkbox Selected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Working with a Material UI Data Grid with check boxes and basically I need the "Next" button to become enabled once at least one item is checked. I've always set the default status of the button to disabled, but I'm stuck on how to enable the button upon at least one row (checkbox) being selected.

Comment: Hi! Can you share your code so I can help you out, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation, you can use [Controlled Selection](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/selection/#controlled-selection) for the Data Grid of Material UI. By this method, you can maintain a `state` in your (parent) component and update it through `onSelectionModelChange` prop of `DataGrid`. Thus, you can check if that `state`(array) has any length and disable/enable the button accordingly.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@material-ui/data-grid';
import { useDemoData } from '@material-ui/x-grid-data-generator';

export default function ControlledSelectionGrid() {
  const { data } = useDemoData({
    dataSet: 'Commodity',
    rowLength: 10,
    maxColumns: 6,
  });

  const [selectionModel, setSelectionModel] = React.useState([]);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        checkboxSelection
        onSelectionModelChange={(newSelectionModel) => {
          setSelectionModel(newSelectionModel);
        }}
        selectionModel={selectionModel}
        {...data}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Please remember to pass the state through `selectionModel` prop to the `DataGrid`. I have attached a CodeSandbox example with a `Button`.

**Sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-sea-riwmx?file=/src/App.js**

Comment: @shadimahfouz please accept (tick) the answer, if it worked.

Comment: I did but it won’t display my vote since I’m still new. It says that my response has been recorded though. Thank you again!

Comment: @shadimahfouz no, I haven't asked to vote. There's a tick sign beside my answer. As you said this worked, then click on the tick to mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: I just noticed that, sorry, I ticked it.